# How to associate a separate station to a Wifi AP

Tags: linux, networking, wifi, bridge

My Linux machine (A) is connected with some Wifi AP over my wireless device (`wlan0`). I want to give some other Linux machine (B), which is connected to me by ethernet (`eth0`), access to this network. I do not want to use NAT. I create a `bridge` device and bridge `wlan0` and `eth0`.

This does not work. I suspect the main reason lies in the fact that B’s MAC was never associated to the AP, so the AP would simply drop B’s packets.

If B would know at this point that his ethernet is bridged to wireless, could it associate to the AP itself? Is it necessary to know the network credentials to do this (after all, it is bridged over my already-secured connection)?

If this is not possible, could I somehow associate B’s MAC for it? And are there other obstacles in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You can't bridge WLAN APs to LAN, because the default three-address mode WLAN protocol won't allow a second MAC bridged to the STA MAC (though it allows a second MAC bridged to an AP MAC, so you have a proper distribution system with many APs and a bridged gateway).

That's a FAQ, and comes up pretty often here.

> If B would know at this point that his ethernet is bridged to wireless, could it associate to the AP itself?

No, for the same reason: Not enough MAC address fields in the protocol.

> Is it necessary to know the network credentials to do this (after all, it is bridged over my already-secured connection)?

You can associate a **second** station (using network credentials, with different encryption keys) if your WLAN hardware allows multiple stations. Then you can use something like "WLAN kabel" application (will have to dig for the link if necessary) to steal packets from the interface and forward it to the LAN interface, and back. This will make the second station disappear on A , and allow a single other device B on the LAN to appear as the STA.

You can also switch to four-address mode, then you can bridge all you want (but this needs to be done on all WLAN devices).